# My vscode overriding nautilus when opening hard-drives

Tags: visual-studio-code

I installed vscode on ubuntu and it keeps on opening hard drives by default. It also opens up when I open a downloads location from my browser. How can I restore nautilus as my default when running these operations?

Answer (score 5):

The `Open With Other Application > Files > Select` didn't work form me. What worked instead was this:

```
xdg-mime default org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop inode/directory
```

And change `org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop` for your specific file manager if needed.

This fix is explained in the session **3.3 Directories are not opened in the file manager** [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/File_manager_functionality#Directories_are_not_opened_in_the_file_manager).

Answer (score 2):

Same issue for me with vscode in Manjaro (Gnome).

I found the answer in the archlinux wiki.
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GNOME/Files#Files_is_no_longer_the_default_file_manager

> This can be caused by the file association for directories being reset. Installing anjuta tends to do this.
>
> To solve this, open Files, right-click on a folder, and choose Open With Other Application > Files > Select. This will set the association for directories back to Files.